Java TreeMap, sort based on attribute of the value (not the key)
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
}

TreeMap<String, Person> m;

Example usage
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.name="name1";
p1.age=32;

Person p2 = new Person();
p2.name="name2";
p2.age=38;

m.put(p1.name,p1);
m.put(p2.name,p2);

How do I tell the lib for TreeMap to sort based on the age attribute and not on the Key? If that is not allowed, what is the way to have such a logic implemented?

@OneCricketeer Passing a Comparator to the constructor of a TreeMap sorts keys, not values. See doc.

This question is similar to: TreeMap sort by value. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, you can't sort on something not in key.
Solution is to have another TreeMap.

Trying to understand the ans better. You are saying put the custom class as Key and override equals and hashcode?

@curiousengineer It should implement Comparable in order to be sorted

@curiousengineer OneCricketeer is trying to be helpful. They are saying that Person should implement Comparable so it sorts properly when you make it the key of a TreeMap. Also, please do not be so hostile; an honest misunderstanding is not "spamming."

A TreeMap sorts entries by the keys, not the values. For this reason, you can try maintaing a second TreeMap to achieve your goal:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    final String name;
    final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        int ageComparison = Integer.compare(this.age, other.age);
        if (ageComparison != 0) {
            return ageComparison;
        }
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{name='" + name + "', age=" + age + '}';
    }
}

class PersonOrganizer {
    private final TreeMap<String, Person> personsByName = new TreeMap<>();
    private final TreeMap<Integer, List<Person>> personsByAge = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        personsByName.put(person.name, person);
        personsByAge.computeIfAbsent(person.age, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(person);
    }

    public void displayPersonsByName() {
        System.out.println("Persons by Name:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Person> entry : personsByName.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void displayPersonsByAge() {
        System.out.println("Persons by Age:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Person>> entry : personsByAge.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Age: " + entry.getKey() + " -> Persons: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getPersonsSortedByAge() {
        List<Person> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Person> personList : personsByAge.values()) {
            sortedList.addAll(personList);
        }
        return sortedList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonOrganizer organizer = new PersonOrganizer();
        Person person1 = new Person("Alice", 32);
        Person person2 = new Person("Bob", 38);
        Person person3 = new Person("Charlie", 32);
        Person person4 = new Person("Diana", 25);
        organizer.addPerson(person1);
        organizer.addPerson(person2);
        organizer.addPerson(person3);
        organizer.addPerson(person4);
        organizer.displayPersonsByName();
        System.out.println();
        organizer.displayPersonsByAge();
        System.out.println("\nAll Persons Sorted by Age:");
        for (Person person : organizer.getPersonsSortedByAge()) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }
}

Output:
Persons by Name:
Name: Alice -> Person{name='Alice', age=32}
Name: Bob -> Person{name='Bob', age=38}
Name: Charlie -> Person{name='Charlie', age=32}
Name: Diana -> Person{name='Diana', age=25}

Persons by Age:
Age: 25 -> Persons: [Person{name='Diana', age=25}]
Age: 32 -> Persons: [Person{name='Alice', age=32}, Person{name='Charlie', age=32}]
Age: 38 -> Persons: [Person{name='Bob', age=38}]

All Persons Sorted by Age:
Person{name='Diana', age=25}
Person{name='Alice', age=32}
Person{name='Charlie', age=32}
Person{name='Bob', age=38}

Try on godbolt.org

One Q. I think the fact that second map uses Age as the key leads to sorted output. Was there a specific reason to have a comparator in the Person class? Without that also, your solution will work right?

Yup, you are right; it's helpful to define when you want to sort if you just had an ArrayList, TreeSet, etc. of people, though.

Nope
No, you cannot sort a TreeMap by values. You can sort a SequencedMap, NavigableMap, or SortedMap such as TreeMap by keys, but not by values.
List < Map.Entry < String , Person > >
As an alternative, you can sort a SequencedCollection like a List such as an ArrayList whose elements are Map.Entry objects.
Something like this untested rough draft where we get Map.Entry objects by calling Map#entrySet.
record Person ( String name , Integer age ) {}

Map < String , Person > map = … ;

List < Map.Entry < String , Person > > entries = new ArrayList <> ( map.entrySet() ) ;
Collections.sort( 
    entries , 
    Map.Entry.comparingByValue ( Comparator.comparing ( Person :: age ) ) 
) ;

As an alternative to a List, you could do something similar for a SequencedSet < Map.Entry < String , Person > > such as TreeSet.
